# ./gradlew assembleRelease BUILD FAILED with Could not find com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker:2.21.0

Tags: android, react-native, expo, release

It's a react-native project with expo bare workflow.
`./gradlew assembleDebug` works normally and I'm able to run the app.

However `./gradlew assembleRelease` build fails with the following output:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':expo-json-utils:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker:2.21.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/Users/<MY USERNAME>/.m2/repository/com/linkedin/dexmaker/dexmaker/2.21.0/dexmaker-2.21.0.pom
       - file:/Users/<MY PROJECT PATH>/node_modules/react-native/android/com/linkedin/dexmaker/dexmaker/2.21.0/dexmaker-2.21.0.pom
       - file:/Users/<MY PROJECT PATH>/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/linkedin/dexmaker/dexmaker/2.21.0/dexmaker-2.21.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/linkedin/dexmaker/dexmaker/2.21.0/dexmaker-2.21.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/linkedin/dexmaker/dexmaker/2.21.0/dexmaker-2.21.0.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/linkedin/dexmaker/dexmaker/2.21.0/dexmaker-2.21.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :expo-json-utils > io.mockk:mockk-android:1.10.6 > io.mockk:mockk-agent-android:1.10.6
```

`expo-json-utils` is not listed in `package.json` dependencies so it must be a child dependency of one of the packages.
Adding `jcenter()` to `android/build.gradle` doesn't fix the issue.

Any ideas which package may use `expo-json-utils` or how to get rid of this issue?

Comment: I assume you already tried but maybe try to delete the node_modules folder and run npm i --save to re-install.  A lot of times, this fixed any similar issue for me.  

Also after re-installing the packages, cleaning and re-building the project in Android Studio then running assembleRelease would help.

Comment: @AleksandarZoric, yes, I tried, didn't help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 problems.

1. Expo and related packages were updated recently and these lines were still in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/expo-constants/scripts/get-app-config-android.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/expo-updates/scripts/create-manifest-android.gradle"
```

They should be removed.

2. Still need to add `jcenter()` to `android/build.gradle` file's section:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
```

Looks like only the latest version `2.28.1`  is added to maven central:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.linkedin.dexmaker/dexmaker-mockito

Older versions are in jcenter and transitive dependency version from `expo-json-utils@0.2.0` is `2.21.0`

Comment: I have the same error but I don't have any lines that start with 'apply from'. Also, adding jcenter didn't solve the issue for me

Comment: Hello, did anyone managed to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Addidng `jcenter()` to the `settings.gradle` solved the issue:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // <- this
    }
}
```